# Check if array is empty or not C++

Tags: c++

Please tell me how to check whether array is empty on not?
see my code after the step of code modify comment.I want a message "Sorry no value added so far".

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int count=0;
//----------------------------------------------------------//
//---------menu items list start from this position---------//
//----------------------------------------------------------//
void menu(int n){cout<<"\nEnter an option: \n";
    cout<<"1- Add new value\n2- Search Value\n3- Modify value\n4- Print Value\n5- Print sum of all values\n6- Quit/terminate\n";
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------//
//---------Funtion to add new values starts from here--------//
//-----------------------------------------------------------//
void AddNewValue(int a[]){
    cout<<"Enter a value\n";
    cin>>a[count];  //taking input to array
    count++;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//---------Function to search a value from array starts from here---------//
//------------------------------------------------------------------------//
void SearchValue(int a[]){
    int num,jawad=0;
    cout<<"Enter a number to search\n";
    cin>>num;
    for(int starter=0;starter<count;starter++){         //starting loop from 1st value of array
        if (num==a[starter])
        jawad=1;        //switching jawad from 0 to 1 if value found
    }
    if(jawad==1)
    cout<<"value exists at "<<count<<"th position\n";
    else cout<<"Value does not exist";
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------//
//---------Function to modify value in array start from here---------//
//-------------------------------------------------------------------//
void ModifyValue(int a[]){
    int modification,position;
    cout<<"Enter the position of a number to modify";
    cin>>position;
    cout<<"Enter a number to modify";
    cin>>modification;
    a[position-1]=modification;         //calculating index from enterd value and placing that equal to new number
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------//
//---------Function to Print values starts from here---------//
//-----------------------------------------------------------//
void PrintValue(int a[]){
    cout<<"The stored values are : ";
    for(int c=0;c<count;c++)        //start loop and tak out all the values then print them
    {cout<<a[c]<<' ';
    if (a[c]==0)
    cout<<"jawad adil";
    }

}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//----------Function to Take sum of the values of array starts from here--------//
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
void PrintSum(int a[]){
    int r=0,sum=0;
    cout<<"The sum of all the values is : ";
    while(r<count){
        sum=sum+a[r];           //taking sum of all the values using loop
        r=r+1;
    }
cout<<sum<<'\n';
}
//---------------------------------------------//
//----------main body starts from here---------//
//---------------------------------------------//
int main(){
    int n;
    int a[100];
    while(n!=6){
    menu(n);
    cin>>n;
    if (n==1){
        AddNewValue(a);         //calling functions using if else statments
    }
    else if(n==2){
        SearchValue(a);
    }
    else if(n==3){
        ModifyValue(a);
    }
    else if(n==4){
        PrintValue(a);
    }
    else if(n==5){
        PrintSum(a);
    }}
 }
```

how can I do that? I am doing but it is not working.

Comment: Arrays have no concept of "empty". It would be better to use [standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Comment: Don't use global variables or C-style arrays.  Use a vector which knows its size.

Comment: Haven't you noticed that you're using the `count` variable to keep track of how many elements there are?

Comment: in your code if count==0, then array is empty

Answer (score 2):

You should add a "check" in your "modify" function.

Original:

```
void ModifyValue(int a[]){
int modification,position;
cout<<"Enter the position of a number to modify";
cin>>position;
cout<<"Enter a number to modify";
cin>>modification;
a[position-1]=modification;
```

With "check":

```
void ModifyValue(int a[]){
//Check
if(count == 0)
{
   cout << "Sorry no value added so far";
   return; //Exit from function
}

int modification,position;
cout<<"Enter the position of a number to modify";
cin>>position;
cout<<"Enter a number to modify";
cin>>modification;
a[position-1]=modification;
}
```

Also I recommend you to use [`switch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/k0t5wee3.aspx) instead of "if else if"

```
if (n==1){
    AddNewValue(a);         //calling functions using if else statments
}
else if(n==2){
    SearchValue(a);
}
else if(n==3){
    ModifyValue(a);
}
else if(n==4){
    PrintValue(a);
}
else if(n==5){
    PrintSum(a);
}
```

like:

```
switch (n)  
  {  
     case 1:  
        AddNewValue(a);  
        break;

     case 2:  
        SearchValue(a);  
        break;

     case 3:  
        ModifyValue(a);;  
        break;

     //And so on...

     default:  
        cout << "Unknown option";  
  }
```

Also in this code you don't need any arguments in

```
  void menu(int n)
```

So you can make

```
  void menu()
```

instead.

Also I recommend you to place whitespaces between operands and operators (words)

```
cout << "Enter a value\n";
cin >> a[count];  //taking input to array
count++;
```

instead

```
cout<<"Enter a value\n";
cin>>a[count];  //taking input to array
count++;
```